# Using php header redirect inside ternary shorthand?

Tags: php, header, shorthand

I'm wondering if it's possible to replicate:

```
if ($a = 1) {
    header('Location: http://google.com');
    exit;
} else {
    header('Location http://yahoo.com');
    exit;
}
```

Using short hand? Maybe...

```
$a = 1 ? header('Location: http://google.com') : header('Location http://yahoo.com');
exit;
```

This does not seem to work, meaning I'm always redirected to google.  =(

Comment: `header('Location ' . $a == 1 ? 'http://google.com' : 'http://yahoo.com');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
header ( 'Location: ' . ( $a == 1 ? 'http://google.com' : 'http://yahoo.com' ) );
```

Note that `$a = 1` is an assignment and will always evaluate to `true`. You need `==` to  achieve comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($a = 1) {
```

it should be

```
if ($a == 1) {
```

and

```
$a = 1 ?
```

should be

```
$a == 1 ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$location= $a == 1 ? "http://google.com" : "http://yahoo.com";
header("Location: $location");
```

Also `=` is assignment operator not a comparison operator. That should be `==` or `===`

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it as is.

Using a ternary here is terrible for readability - which code block will be easier and faster to understand for a new programmer inheriting your code?